# css: How to float div according to 2nd div in hierarchy

Tags: css, layout

I need this blue div to be next to red div, while yellow div must remain in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/pCGxe/

How to do this without using something like `position:absolute, float:none` - etc... nasty hacks?

Comment: Why do you think absolute positioning is a nasty hack?

Comment: because my site is a lot more complex than this little example. The content is dynamic and it just wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `margin-top: -50px` to the big div.

Alternatively, you can also wrap the small divs in another div, and float that. Depends on the situation.

And `position: absolute`, `float: none` are not nasty hacks at all, they are the best friends of a sitebuilder :).

Comment: I can't use margin-top: -50px; There are actually more divs before these "3 example divs" and they are dynamic. I guess I should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: This solution might still work even under those circumstances. If you can give me a jsFiddle displaying what you *actually* want I might be able to help you better :).

Comment: I messed around with different techniques. I was left with either using this margin css "hack" (sorry, but imo it is), or using jQuery to manipulate html. I chose to use negative margin. So I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thx for accepting. Still, imo if you use CSS functionality according to the CSS spec, it can never be considered a hack. Negative margins is a perfectly valid technique.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add margins with fixed numbers and especially no margins with fixed negative numbers. What if your site's design or the size of the divs changes later? You'd need to change all those margins.

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/pCGxe/10/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1and2">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bigdiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1and2 {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: .. but is he looking for a pure CSS solution?

Comment: @Richard, I assume so based on the fact that there is only a `css` tag on the question

Comment: but you changed the HTML... I agree with your points, however.

Comment: @Richard, fair enough, if the HTML is not to be changed, my answer is non-applicable. I would still argue it is the best approach though, better than adding static number margins or absolute positioning according to the size of the red div.

Comment: This is the method I would usually use in this situation, but I can't change HTML source. Not in this manner, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion absolute positioning is not a hack, rather most developers just don't know how to use it - it's almost like occult CSS knowledge :P

So here's an example of how absolute positioning could be used to solve this particular problem:

```
#container{
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px dashed black;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#div1{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
#div2{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
}
#bigdiv{
    width:350px;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:0px;
    background:blue;
}
```

In order for absolute positioning to work properly, one of the ancestor elements of the absolutely positioned element (in this case `#bigdiv`) has to be positioned non-statically. `position:static` is the default positioning for any element, so if I want `#bigdiv` to be `50px`away from the left side of `#container`, `#container` has to have non-static positioning; hence the `position:relative;`.

For the record, `float:none` is *definitely* not a hack :P

Comment: In theory, this would seem like a nice way to get this to work. But again, using position:absolute near divs that contain dynamic data is not a very good idea in my oppinion.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#container{
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px dashed black;
}
#div1{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
#div2{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
}
#bigdiv{
    width:350px;
    height:250px;
    float:right;
    background:blue;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="bigdiv"></div>   
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the size of `container` changes later? then the `margin-right` needs to be changed as well? Or even more interesting, what if the width of `container` is non-fixed?

Comment: You changed HTML. I can't have "bigdiv" before div1 and div2.